# How the batch tuples transport in Jstorm Trident when do a rebalance？

Tags: jstorm

When i use trident in jstorm,tuples in one batch which have same fields will be send to different tasks after rebalance,so how does the trident's CombinerAggregator work?

Answer (score 0):

if the task num changed，jstorm can't ensure that tuples of same field are sent to same tasks。so，when we do rebalance in jstorm，we should be ca